# Looping the number inside array - React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

I have an array

```
let counterArray = [5];
```

I need to loop 5 times

```
{counterArray .map(counter=>
    <span>Counter- {counter}</span>
)}
```

This will just display the counter. How do i loop the counter?

For Suppose if i have

```
let counterArray = [15];
```

.map has to loop 15 times. Basically converting the number to loop. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use `range` from `lodash`

```
import { range } from 'lodash'
<div>
  {
    range(5).map((item, index) => (
      <div key={index}>{index}</div>
    ))
  }
</div>
```

Comment: Found this as pretty easiest one. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just build up an array of the given length and loop over that:

```
   Array.from({ length: counterArray[0] }, (_, i) => i)
    .map(counter => <Counter {counter} />)
```

Alternatively may just use a good old for loop:

```
  const res = [];

  for(let counter = 0; counter < counterArray[0]; counter++)
    res.push(<Counter {counter} />);

  return res;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let counterArray = [5];
```

will just create an array of single item with value 5

Use `Array` constructor here

```
let counterArray = [...new Array(5)].map( (s, i) => i );
```

This will create an array with value being the counter value - `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Oh, building 3 temporary arrays. Sounds efficient :)